# How to fix the error "Unexpected end of JSON input" when running npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, asdf

I'm facing an ISSUE when I run the command `npm install`. The error output is shown below.

```
npm verb stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...fines what it needs i'
npm verb stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
npm verb stack     at parseJson (/home/edy/.asdf/installs/nodejs/14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
npm verb stack     at /home/edy/.asdf/installs/nodejs/14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50
npm verb stack     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
npm verb stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
npm verb cwd /home/edy/projects/godaddy/mercury
npm verb Linux 5.15.41-1-MANJARO
npm verb argv "/home/edy/.asdf/installs/nodejs/14.15.5/bin/node" "/home/edy/.asdf/installs/nodejs/14.15.5/bin/npm" "-dd" "install"
npm verb node v14.15.5
npm verb npm  v6.14.11
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...fines what it needs i'
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
```

Basically, the error says `JSON input while parsing near '{this part vary}'`. I tried some things to fix this but nothing worked.

I tried cleaning the cache running `npm cache clean --force && rm -rf ~/.npm`, and running the command to install dependencies again but it didn't work.

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks for any help.

Node Version: 14.15.5
NPM Version: 6.14.11

(I'm using [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com) to manage the versions)

Comment: what does the package.json in your project look like?

Comment: okay, let me check with my boss if I can share it. are you suspecting that this is a dependency error?

Comment: It may be malformed.

Comment: Another thing to check is to grep the directory for "fines what it needs i". Where is that coming from?